# Unable to run the easiest gettext + PHP sample

Tags: php, localization, translation, gettext

Using PHP 5.6.11, I try to run the easiest gettext+PHP sample (`test.php`):

```
$language = 'de';
putenv("LANG=$language"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "/home/foo/www/locale"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($domain);

echo gettext("Hello_World");
```

In the `/home/foo/www/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES` directory, I created a file called `messages.po` :

```
msgid "Hello_World"
msgstr "Hallo Welt"
```

I converted it to `messages.mo` with `Poedit` and even with the `msgfmt` shell command.

However, when I run `localhost/test.php`, I get only `"Hello_World"`, and not `"Hallo Welt"`.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Which server setup are you using?